# order by and distinct in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

The following event handler is returning it's list but it is not distinct. There are still many duplicates in the list.Any thoughts?

```
Protected Sub ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlState.SelectedIndexChanged
    If IsPostBack Then
        ddlCity.Items.Clear()
        Dim context As New teckEntities()
        Using context
            'Dim query = From c In context.counties Where c.stateid = ddlState.SelectedValue Select c.countyname, c.id
            Dim query = From c In context.ziptaxes Where c.StateID = ddlState.SelectedValue Order By c.City Select c.City, c.ZipTaxId
            query.Distinct()
            ddlCity.DataSource = query.ToList()
            ddlCity.DataValueField = "ziptaxid"
            ddlCity.DataTextField = "City"
            ddlCity.DataBind()
        End Using
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the return value of the query after you have applied the `distinct` filter.

```
 ddlCity.DataSource = query.Distinct().ToList()
 ddlCity.DataValueField = "ziptaxid"
 ddlCity.DataTextField = "City"
 ddlCity.DataBind()
```

Comment: Ive made the change, ty. But the list still has duplicates. Does distinct only remove 1 duplicate? this list sometimes has 4-5 duplicates in it.

Comment: @dinotom What is the SQL query generated by the LINQ query after you have applied `Distinct`?

Comment: I created a stored procedure and call that from entity framework, was much easier